# Image in a NSPopUpButtonCell with NSArrayController and Core Data

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

This is the scenario: A Core Data model with an entity which contains a relationship to a second entity. The latter entity contains an attribute which is an image and a second attribute with is a name (`NSString`).

The GUI is a `NSTableView` which is bound to a `NSArrayController`. One column of the table is a `NSPopUpButtonCell`. It is setup so that it currently contains the names of the second entity. It works well so far.

The problem is that I would like to show the image instead of the name. `NSPopUpButtonCell` is  basically able to show images but I'm not able to setup the proper bindings. Setting the bindings directly in the cell doesn't work and the column binding of the table view doesn't feature an image as binding.

It's a little bit complicated but maybe someone can gibe me a hint!

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Why does "Setting the bindings directly in the cell" not "work"?

Comment: Because AFAIK the cell is a representation of just ONE cell and the table column handles the whole array of cells of which the table column consists. So binding arranged objects to a single cell doesn't make sense.